# Column C to list missing items from comparison of Columns A and B

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2013

I have column A with 1860 items and Column B with 1650 similar items.  How do I in column C list the missing items from column B?

Comment: This is the function of `Advanced Filter`, learn how to use it from [here](http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/advanced-filter.html)

Answer (score 0):

With data like:

[image]

Hi-light **C2** through **C11** and enter the *Array Formula*:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(A2:A11,B2:B11,0)),A2:A11,"")
```

*Array Formulas* must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

What we now have is:

[image]

Each missing name is listed near its value in column **A**

From:  [Pearsons website](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ListFunctions.aspx)